# Message Routing in Azure IoT Hub returning application/octet-stream

Tags: json, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am routing messages from an Azure IoT Hub to a blob container ([Azure Storage as a routing endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#azure-storage-as-a-routing-endpoint)). The messages sent to the IoT Hub are of Content Type: 'application/json' and Content Encoding: 'UTF-8'. However, when they arrive in blob storage several of these messages are batched together into one file with Content Type 'application/octet-stream'. Thus, for instance Power BI is not able to read these files in JSON format when reading directly from the blob.

- Is there any way to route these messages so that each single message is saved as a json file in the blob container?

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr  : Please make use of the **Encoding** option to specify AVRO or JSON format & **Batch Frequency/Size** to control the batch.

"With an Azure Storage container as a custom endpoint, IoT Hub will write messages to a blob based on the **batch frequency** and **block size** *specified by the customer*. After either the batch size or the batch frequency is hit, whichever happens first, IoT Hub will then write the enqueued messages to the storage container as a blob. You can also specify the naming convention you want to use for your blobs, as shown below."

- **The below image shows how we navigate to the IoTHub's message routing section to add a custom endpoint of a blob storage account.**

[image]

**-The below image shows how we configure the settings of the batch count and the size. Also please make use of the Encoding section to specify the message format such as AVRO or JSON**

[image]

Please leave a comment below to let us know if you need further help in this matter.

Comment: I am well aware of the batch and chunk settings. However, these do not seem to affect the stucture in the way I want. I have my encoding set to JSON but when I look at the files in Azure storage explorer the Content Type is still set to application/octet-stream.

They appear in JSON format but without any separation by commas between the different JSON-objects. Thus, the files in blob are not recognized as being of valid json format.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, let me also take a look at this scenario...will keep you posted.

Comment: got the same problem nowadays, did you find any solution oh wise men who came before me? :D

Comment: Could you please log a product question or issue on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/25494/azure-iot-hub.html), please use the tag azure-iot-hub, a team of experts will help you immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The message encoding needs to be done by the device stream or as part of a module to translate the protocol. Each protocol (AMQP, MQTT, and HTTP) uses a different method to encode the message from base64 to UTF-8.

To route messages based on message body, you must first add property 'contentType' (ct) to the end of the MQTT topic and set its value to be application/json;charset=utf-8. An example is shown below.

```
devices/{device-id}/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support